# Setting Up a Website on a domain from godaddy using google web app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to set up a website with my projects. I already have a domain I bought from https://www.godaddy.com. This is my first website so I have no idea how to go on. My preference is to use python google app engine. I will want database support, but currently, I just want to put a static website on the web. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked through the google app engine tutorials?

Comment: I already have and had no luck.